# How do I name and get my listall() method to be called on my program?

Tags: java

I am new to coding, and I am doing a class project, I am suppose to write a main class that reads from the file and then do several stuff with it.

I am having trouble getting my listall() method to work, I am not sure how to name is or what the parameters (if any) should be. I am trying to get a value from the keyboard and depending on a value call a certain method, for now I only have the listall() method and I want the user to input l or L and that would make the listall() method be called.

However I have been trying since the morning and looking through various tutorials but I don't understand how I am suppose to set this up. Help? I have already tested a lot with my program, I can use it to get certain attributes that I want from my 'candidate class' I created. Here is my code for my main class, i have commented out certain lines to work on specific parts of the program.
please help, I am lost.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class appl {

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException

{ String fileName = "C:/Users/mrodri34/Documents/cipcs115.txt";

File candidates = new File(fileName);

Scanner scan = new Scanner(candidates);
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
String state = scan.next();
int numOfCan = scan.nextInt();
String what = scan.nextLine();
//System.out.println(what);
int count = 1; 
int i;
int o = 1;
Candidate [] candi = new Candidate[3];
for ( i=0; i<numOfCan; i++)
{ 
String three = scan.next();
String four = scan.next();
String five = scan.next();
int six = scan.nextInt();
double seven = scan.nextDouble();
String eight = scan.nextLine();
//String nine = scan.nextLine();
Candidate night  = new Candidate (three,four,five,six,seven,eight);
candi [i] = night ; 
System.out.println(night.getName() + "  " + night.getMotto());
}
System.out.println(candi[0].getName());
System.out.println(candi[1].getName());
//Candidate [] candi = new Candidate[3];
//Candidate night = new Candidate (three,four,five,six,seven,eight);
//candi [0] = night;

//System.out.println(eight);
//System.out.println(six);
//System.out.println(seven);
//System.out.println(five);
System.out.println(state);
//System.out.println(what);
System.out.println(numOfCan);
//System.out.println(three);
//System.out.println(four);
//System.out.println("First candidate is " + candi[0].getName());
//System.out.println(candi[0].getNumberOfVotes());
//System.out.println(night.toString());
//System.out.println(night.getParty());
System.out.println(" what would you like to do? >");
String option = user.next();
switch (option)
{case "l":
case "L":
listall();
break;
}
scan.close();  
}
public static Candidate listall()
{
return candi[0].getName() + "   " + candi[1].getName();
}
}
```

also here is the error messages when I run this code

```
appl.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
return candi[0].getName() + "   " + candi[1].getName();
       ^
  symbol:   variable candi
  location: class appl
appl.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
return candi[0].getName() + "   " + candi[1].getName();
                                ^
  symbol:   variable candi
  location: class appl
2 errors
```

I was able to fix my previous problems but now something funny is happening.

```
public static String listall()
{  System.out.println(candi[0].getMotto());
return candi[0].getName();
}
```

when I run this code, the output will show the System.out command but it will not give me the return command, does anyone know why that may be?

Comment: I understand you are new to development. But it would be helpful if you removed unneeded code, and then formatted the remaining code. It will make it easier on the folks who are trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The candi array is not accessible for an outside method, so you need to include a field variable or a getCandidates() method.

Something like this:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class appl {

    private static Candidates[] candi;

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    { 
        //Initialize array in here
    }

    public static String listall()
    {
        return candi[0].getName() + "   " + candi[1].getName();
    }
}
```

or with a method:

import java.io.*;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class appl {

    private Candidates[] candi;

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    { 
        //Initialize array in here
    }
    public Candidate[] getCandidateArray()
    {
        return candi;
    }
    public static String listall()
    {
        Candidate[] temp = getCandidateArray();
        return temp[0].getName() + "   " + temp[1].getName();
    }
}
```

Also note that your listAll method returns a string, and therefore its return type should be string not Candidate

Comment: thank you for the quick and well thought out response, I think I have fixed my initial problem, however when compiling my code I now receive a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" and I am not sure what it means but I know it has to do with my switch case statement and the way it is calling the listall() method, I am not quite sure were the problem is because Its suppose to be some kind of initializing problem if I am not mistaken, but I do not know what I should be initializing to null.